# fluid content layout issue with css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a layout issue:

```
.sectorMenuContentPane {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.sectorContentPane {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

.sectorContentPaneRight {
    float: right;
    width: 32%;
}
```

Here are my layouts using the same css:
[image: Layouts]

In the 3 column layout the page looks fine but in the 2 column layout its broken. How can i make it so if there isnt a sectorContentPaneRight then sectorContentPane fills the area as per my diagram?

Also as if i need it fluid? Can you help me with a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Post a jsfiddle so we can play with it.

Comment: Is .sectorContentPaneRight nested in .sectorContentPane?

Comment: I posted an answer using tables anyway :-) It's not table markup though, just divs using the display table property

Comment: _How can i make it so if there isnt a sectorContentPaneRight then sectorContentPane fills the area as per my diagram_ : is this question reversed? Your image is asking the opposite

Comment: I assume it's a typo in the diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables will be your easiest solution. Here's an example using divs with `display: table`

http://jsfiddle.net/9x2SC/

The left and right cells have a set width. The center one will fill the remaining space. This will be your only 100% css solution. You could use Javascript to determine what to do and apply a class to the wrapper element, but this is more elegant (in my opinion.)

css:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.sectorMenuContentPane {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
}

.sectorContentPane {
    display: table-cell;
}

.sectorContentPaneRight {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 32%;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/JdpYP/

css

```
.menu {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.slider {
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
}
```

just avoid to float the rightmost div

Comment: nice example, but as per query: inside second div, content won't be present: it would be only menu and slider; where it doesn't work.

Comment: I think I've not understood your comment: In the OP example the second image is without slider

Comment: In your eg. you have menu,slider and content in 1st div; and menu and content in 2nd div. Whereas it should have been menu and slider in second div as per question.

Comment: Oh, you are right: images and question tell the opposite. I've asked to OP in a comment above

Answer (score 1):

Now as you know that CSS3 is being used by a lot of them..

This can be done easily using CSS3.

Here is how you do it..

```
.containerOfDivs{
   width:950px;
   display:-webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-flex: 1;
   -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
}

.sectorMenuContentPane{
   width: 250px;
}

.sectorContentPane {
   display:-webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}

.sectorContentPaneRight {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the kind of thing you are after?

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="right">
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>

<style>
    #menu { width:25%; height:400px; border:2px solid #000; float:left; margin-right:10px; }
    #slider, #content { width:48%; height:400px; border:2px solid #000; float:left; margin-right:10px; }
    #right { width:74%; height:400px; float:left; }
</style>
```